# how retrieval Internal work flow of cosmos DB works?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

How the data stored? what are the rules to write data and make efficient retrieval?

Does the level4  based retrieval condition affects the performance?

```
{level1:{level2:{level3:[{level4:""}]}} }
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but... Cosmos DB abstracts the storage layer - you can read up on its physical and logical partitioning schemes, and somewhere is a whitepaper detailing some lower-level information. As for query performance: Please show your specific query and where you're having issues. Each query advertises its resulting Request Unit cost, so you can compare different queries to see if there are cost differences. Also note that, in your example document, your level 4 data is contained in an array in level 3 - does that mean you're testing for "array contains?"

Comment: Per my last comment: there's enough ambiguity even in the performance question, that it cannot be answered objectively without specifics (e.g. your query). Also, there is a lot of information already published, in the Cosmos DB docs, for looking at Request Unit cost, both via portal and via code. I would start there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS David says,Cosmos DB has **Logical partitions** and **Physical partitions**.One or more logical partitions are mapped to a single physical partition.Each logical partition can store up to 20GB of data.Choosing a good partition key is very important,it affects your throughput consumption and  stored procedures or triggers.More details refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview).

About 'Does the level4 based retrieval condition affects the performance?',this is related to your query.I create a sample:

```
{
    "class": "dog",
    "pets": {
        "dog": {
            "Huskies": [
                {
                    "name": "happy",
                    "age": 2
                },
                {
                    "name": "Louis",
                    "age": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

If you use this sql:`SELECT * FROM c`,it's request charge is 2.28 RUs.

If you use this sql:`SELECT c.class,h.name,h.age FROM c join h in c.pets.dog.Huskies`,it's request charge is 3.06 RUs.

I just created one document,the gap between two sql will be large if you has lots of  document.About query performance,you can read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-query-metrics).

Hope this can help you.